# Modern way for building layout

Tags: css, media-queries, flexbox

I am going to start new layout and want build my site using modern technology. What is the best way to build new site?

These are what I have been thinking of using:

- Media Queries+adobe regions+Flexbox
- Media Queries+CSS Grid (from Microsoft)+Flexbox
- Media Queries+Flexbox

I want to hear good advice befor starting my project. Thanks!

Comment: What will the new technology allow you to do that a more tried/tested method won't?

Comment: I wanted to build layout without floating elements..flexbox can do it. I saw the video here http://channel9.msdn.com/events/MIX/MIX11/HTM11 about this

Comment: Do you care about cross-browser compatibility (do you care about IE8 and below)?

Comment: Have you considered using something like Bootstrap, Foundation, Skeleton or semantic.gs? Flexbox is a bit sketchy since IE < 10 don't support it.

Comment: In that case, you can discount everything in your list apart from media queries (and even then you will have to use a js polyfil to get them to work). As cool as new tech is, it is very hard to use when you are trying to reach a broad variety of browsers. The other option is to maintain two different versions of the site - one with the cool new tech and a more basic version for older browsers. That has its own difficulties though.

Comment: I like Boostrap very much and i use it in my progect, but after that video and articles in internet i start thinking that maybe bootstrap and http://cssgrid.net/ maybe now old technology. I want to stay up-to-date

Comment: Thank you for answers! I decided to continue use bootstrap and will biuld layout on flexbox etc now only for learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like [Flexie](http://flexiejs.com/) would be a good choice for your case given you want to use Flexbox. Flexie provides legacy support. Give it a go.